# Please confirm River Song's role in Doctor Who

Tags: doctor-who

> Is River Song Amy Pond's daughter and the Doctor's lover? I'm sorry but I'd be very disconcerted to realize that the person who could potentially kill you, who you love, who is directly related to one of your best friends, and to top it off you have all been meeting backwards in time.

So I'd like to know if this is true or not.

Comment: Wikipedia on [River Song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Song_%28Doctor_Who%29); lays it all out.

Comment: Also, there are probably untold stories that we'll see in the upcoming seventh series.

Answer (score 9):

The only way to answer that is with, as River or the Doctor would say, "spoilers."

> River Song is the result of an attempt to create a weapon that could be used against the Doctor to kill him.  She is Amy Pond's daughter, taken from her at birth.  The next time, in River's timeline, as of now, that she sees Amy is when she appears as Amy's friend Melody.
> It is a rather convoluted timeline, which would probably be much easier to follow if River's timeline (in terms of meeting the Doctor) weren't running backwards.

Comment: Yes, what a twisted story... I wonder how the writers are keeping up.

Comment: @Justin they probably use lots of string.

Comment: @Xantec You mean like a big ball of wibbly-wobbly writy witey ...stuff?

Answer (score 6):

Your information is basically correct. River Song's history is based on her life as a weapon to destroy the Doctor.

This timeline may help:

[image]